# How to get number of occurences in a SQL query, in ZF2

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework2

I have a table of users:

```
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
| 1    | A    |
+------+------+
| 2    | B    |
+------+------+
| 3    | C    |
+------+------+
| 4    | D    |
+------+------+
```

And a relation table users_group:

```
+------+----------+
|user_id|group_id |
+------+----------+
| 1    | 1        |
+------+----------+
| 1    | 2        |
+------+----------+
| 3    | 3        |
+------+----------+
| 4    | 4        |
```

+------+----------+

i have a display in my application to display user data:

```
-------     ---------    ----------------
user id     user name    number of groups
-------     ---------    ----------------
```

In my Zf2 i run the query in my mapper to get the user data:

```
public function fetchAllUsers()
{
$select = $this->getSelect();
$select->from('user');
->join('users_group', 'user.id=users_group.user_id', array(), 'left');  
$users = $this->select($select)->getDataSource();
return $users;
}
```

What i need is, how can i get the number of groups that each user belongs in this same query and return it in the same array to fetch in application and feed the table display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular SQL, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to join the users table to the users_group table, and just use `COUNT` to count the resulting groups;

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, COUNT(ug.group_id) num_groups
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_group ug
  ON u.id = ug.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
ORDER BY u.id
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bff83/3).

In ZF2, it should be something similar to (the untested);

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;

public function fetchAllUsers()
{
  $select = $this->getSelect();
  $select->columns(array('user.id', 'user.name', 
               'num_groups' => new Expression('COUNT(users_group.group_id)')));
  $select->from('user');
  $select->join('users_group', 'user.id=users_group.user_id', array(), 'left');  
  $select->group(array('user.id', 'user.name'));
  $users = $this->select($select)->getDataSource();
  return $users;
}
```

Comment: Perfect Joachim, works like a charm, even the ZF2 code. Thanks for your time, you saved my day!